# Ionic2 & SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin not working toghter

Tags: cordova, ionic

did any of you succeeded in impl ionic2 (3.0.0) & SalesforceMobileSDK plugin?? i just want the OAuth2  flow (login screen etc..).
i saw this tutorial http://coenraets.org/blog/2016/12/sample-application-with-ionic-2-and-salesforce/ which is the only one out there in WildWildWest but it's not working and trying to install the plugin causes conflicts.